# create-react-app doesn't apply eslint rules that are in place like `button-has-type` and `boolean-prop-naming`

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I have generated a React app using `create-react-app`. The generated app comes with eslint and eslint rules like `button-has-type` and `boolean-prop-naming`. However, when I run `npm start`, I don't see any errors that am expecting.

Using above eslint rules I expect the following code to fail

```
<button>Hello</button>
```

and

```
App.propTypes = {
   enabled: PropTypes.bool
};
```

Thanks

Comment: afaik you have no access to ESLint config until doing `eject`. in other words there is a little control on things. maybe it's just a bug in concrete version of `create-react-app`. what version do you use?

Comment: Am using create-reatct-app: 2.0.4. When I inspect inside node modules, there is a folder call `eslint-plugin-react` which itself has `boolean-prop-naming` and `button-has-type` rules. So I don't need to eject.

Comment: actually fact that `eslint` is shipped with some rule does not mean it will be used. I believe [`eslint-config-react-app`](https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app) package is responsible for configuring eslint. It lists rules explicitly and there is neither `button-has-type` nor `boolean-prop-naming`

Answer (score 0):

you can install `npm i -s prop-types` and use prop-types.

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

App.propTypes = {
   enabled: PropTypes.bool
};
```

Comment: I have but according to this: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/boolean-prop-naming.md your code example should give an error. Instead of `enabled`, you should write `isEnabled`, no?